# How to respond using Web Streams like ReadableStream and WritableStream with Koa.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, koa

I am using native [`fetch`](https://nodejs.org/de/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/) provided by Node.js 18 to make and API call which returns the response body as [`ReadableStream`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/webstreams.html#class-readablestream) instance. I simply need to pass the response via Koa.js server to the frontend without doing any manipulation of the response received by fetch and thus piping the stream is most performant way. This is the simplified version of the code:

```js
import Koa from 'koa';

const app = new Koa();

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  
  const response = await fetch('http://api-server:8181');

  // How to make this work with web streams?
  ctx.body = response.body;
});
```

The problem here is that `ctx.body` accepts [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable) instance but not the standard webstreams API - `ReadableStream`. How can I make this work?

*Note: Earlier with Node v16, I used `node-fetch` polyfill which actually used `stream.Readable` instead of `ReadableStream` for [convenience](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/HEAD/docs/v3-LIMITS.md) which was clearly different from standard behavior; but that made this easier which is not the case anymore.*

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.body = Readable.fromWeb(response.body)
```

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: does not work, there will be a type mismatch between ReadableStream expected from fromWeb and the ReadableStream of res.body. for a complete explanation and fix see here. → https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/3862